# Meteor build error on windows 8.1

Tags: meteor, build, windows-8.1

I have installed Meteor on Windows 8.1 - 64 bit to continue developing an existing meteor app. But, I cannot start it.

**Problem**

I run "meteor run": it starts proxy, MongoDB, selects packages, and after the last step, "Building the application", I get an error which I cannot explain (see stack trace). Then, it keeps trying to build the app, and gives the same errors over and over again.

**Strange things**:

1. the exact same project works just fine on Ubuntu and Mac OS - now I want to use Windows 8.1 (note: I have cloned the repository using git)
2. the demo app "todos" works on my meteor on Windows 8.1

**What I tried**

I had reinstalled Meteor, checked the packages (I have both npm&node.js) meteor --test-packages, meteor --reset, google all the info from the trace or any other question about meteor building errors on Windows 8.1, but couldn't solve my problem.

**My questions**:

1. How to make it work?
2. Does it have to do with Windows 8.1 itself or do I just don't have something installed/set on this pc.

**Update 1**

I created a new meteor project and copied all the files to this new folder. I started to add all the packages, and it seems that the problem appears when I add this package:

[oauth-encryption](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/oauth-encryption)

It seems to be the same problem as the one here: https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction/issues/363. But still, can't find the solution.

**Stack trace**

```
C:\Users\Cristi\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-

os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
                                             throw(ex);
                                                   ^
Error: The operating system cannot run %1.
C:\Users\Cristi\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-node-aes-gcm\0.1.3_6\npm\node_modules\node-aes-gcm\build\Release\node_aes_gcm.node
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.Npm.require (D:\Projects\time\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:142:18)
at Package (packages/npm-node-aes-gcm/wrapper.js:2:1)
at D:\Projects\time\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\npm-node-aes-gcm.js:33:4
at D:\Projects\time\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\npm-node-aes-gcm.js:42:3
(STDERR)     at D:\Projects\time\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:222:10
(STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
```

Comment: It seems from the git issue you posted, this is a known issue with reaction core on windows which oauth-encryption uses. They don't have a solution yet.