# Installing Meteor on Windows 7 with Errors

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have installed Npm and Node.js

> ImageMagick - Optional but suggested For windows installation you also
>   need: Win32 OpenSSL Visual Studio 2008 redistributables Git / mysgit

But when I use command; `meteor run` it stills display error below.

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log:
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: The operating system cannot run %1.

C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-node-aes-gcm\0.1.3_6\npm\node_modules\node-aes-gcm\build\Release\node_aes_gcm.node
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.Npm.require (E:\xampp\htdocs\reactioncommerce\reaction\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:162:18)
    at Package (packages/npm-node-aes-gcm/packages/npm-node-aes-gcm.js:10:1)
    at Package (packages/npm-node-aes-gcm/packages/npm-node-aes-gcm.js:25:1)
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\reactioncommerce\reaction\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\npm-node-aes-gcm.js:45:4
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\reactioncommerce\reaction\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\npm-node-aes-gcm.js:54:3
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\reactioncommerce\reaction\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:242:10
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Related question on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309970/meteor-build-error-on-windows-8-1) and corresponding [GitHub issue #363](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction/issues/363).